# What's the best practice for handling loading child resources in ngResource?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Context: I'm new to Angular, and this feels like a lot more of a "What's the right way to do this in AngularJS" kind of question.

My API backend has a couple of related objects that I need to request and assemble into a coherent user interface. It can be modeled as a subscription hub thing, so I have: Subscription hasMany Subscription_Items, belongsTo Source.

What I want to do is look up a user's Subscriptions (/api/subscriptions?user_id=1), which gives me some JSON that includes a subscription_item_ids=[1,2,3 ...] array. I then want to query on those ids, as well as query the server on source_id to pull shared info, and then repackage everything nicely into the $scope so the view layer has easy access to the system and can do stuff like ng-repeat="item in subscription.subscription_items" inside an outer ng-repeat="subscription in subscriptions".

Conceptually this makes sense, and I've thought of a few ways to load this linked data, but what I'm curious about is: what's the best practice here? I don't want to excessively reload the data, so it seems like a plain old function that does a REST request every time I look at an item is a bad idea, but at the same time, I don't want to just push the data in once and then miss out on updates to items.

So, the question is: what's the best way to handle linked resources like this, to trace hasMany and belongsTo types of connections out to other models in a way that aligns with the ideas embedded in $scope and the $apply cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use a lazy-loaded `dataModel` service which will cache results and return promises.  The interface looks like this:

```
dataModel.getInstitution(institutionId).then(manageTheInstitution);
```

If I need something that is a child, I call it like this:

```
dataModel.getStudents(institutionId).then(manageStudents);
```

Internally, `getStudents` looks something like this:

```
function getStudents(institnutionId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    getInstitnution(institutionId).then(function(institution) {
        institution.students = Student.query({institutionId: institutionId});

        institution.students.$promise.then(function(students) {
            deferred.resolve(students);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

These functions are a bit more complex.  They cache the results and don't request them again if they already exist... and return or chain the existing promise.  They also handle errors.

By carefully crafting my `dataModel` service this way, I can manage any nesting of resources and I can optimize my network requests.  I've been very happy with this approach so far.